# 'The application to execute does not exist' error when trying to debug C# in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/with-visual-studio-code) Microsoft article on getting started with C# in Visual Studio Code and everything went smoothly until step 6 in the Debug section: when i clicked the debug button (green arrow) [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GRwI.jpg) is what happend.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing step 3 again.
Hit Ctrl+' (Ctrl backtick)
type dotnet restore

Comment: @Hello_World From the `dotnet restore` you should get some information about certain packages/references that are missing/broken. What is the output for the command?